# Logging in ASP.NET Core 5

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, publish

I have written a project with ASP.NET Core. When I publish the project to the server, my user can not log in for more than 30 minutes, and after 30 minutes, it needs to be re-authenticated and redirected to the login page.

This is my code in the `ConfigureServices` method:

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = false;
        options.LoginPath = "/Login";
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/NotFound";
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(30);
        options.LogoutPath = "/SignOut";
    });
```

And this is in the `Configure` method:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

This problem only occurs when the project is published

Comment: can you edit your title, the word `logging` is misleading.

Answer (score 1):

#### UPDATE

You can find machine key [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43327546/7687666). It will help you solve the issue.

*Reason*

> Application generates new machine key every time when it has been restarted. So way to solve problem is to force application to use constant key.

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        _env = env;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public IWebHostEnvironment _env { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
                services.AddDataProtection()
                        .SetApplicationName($"my-app-{_env.EnvironmentName}")
                        .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo($@"{_env.ContentRootPath}\keys"));
                services.AddControllersWithViews();
    
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

---

Change `FromDays` to `FromMinutes` will help you solve the issue.

```
options.ExpireTimeSpan =  TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30); //TimeSpan.FromDays(30);
```

Comment: I want my user to stay logged in for 30 days